# In the app engine dashbord, requests from uri are displayed that I don't know the origin, does anyone know where it comes from?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, deployment, uri

[Dashboard do App engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbLf3.png)

A friend told me that it looks like wordpres was downloaded along with the app because they are common wordpress uris, but he's not sure. I thought that they were due to Google Cloud services (App engine, Storage, Logging, Build, Secret manager) but I'm not sure either? Is it one of those cases? Is it a problem and if so is there a fix?

Obs: I don't know it it helps, but the site is develop with django, boostrap and jquery.

I even write in browser the uri but nothing that i wouldn't expect appear.
I don't even know how to work with wordpress.

Comment: A known issue with GAE is that it attracts a lot of Spam visits (lots of visits to  ```Wordpress``` related links which result in 404). The solution is to create [Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/creating-firewalls) against each of the IPs. The challenge is that there are lots of them. Our [website](https://nocommandline.com) is currently facing this issue & I'm currently working on a fix for this (to identify and auto create firewall rules; if you'd like to be notified when this is ready, send us an email using the contact us link on our website)

Comment: Check your log explorer and confirm those links end up with a 404 (i.e. the urls don't exist on your site). This tells you that you don't have Wordpress and they're spam. If you search across Google/Stackoverflow, you'll see reports about this

Comment: As earlier mentioned, we were facing the same issue and finally built a [solution](https://firewall.nocommandline.com/) to fix it.